# Dynamic method definition in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

What does `$1.to_sym => args[0]` and `($1.to_sym,*args,&block)` do in the following line of code?

```
class Table
  def method_missing(id,*args,&block)
    return as($1.to_sym,*args,&block) if id.to_s =~ /^to_(.*)/
    return rows_with($1.to_sym => args[0]) if id.to_s =~ /^rows_with_(.*)/
    super
  end
  # ...
end
```

**Context:**
Ruport is a Ruby reporting library. You can use the Ruport::Data::Table class to create tabular data and convert it to different formats—text, for example:

```
require 'ruport'  
table = Ruport::Data::Table.new :column_names => ["country" , "wine" ], :data => [["France" , "Bordeaux" ], ["Italy" , "Chianti" ], ["France" , "Chablis" ]]  
puts table.to_text

⇒    
+--------------------+
| country |   wine   |
+--------------------+
| France | Bordeaux |
| Italy  | Chianti |
| France | Chablis |
+--------------------+
```

Let’s say you select only the French wines and convert them to comma-separated values:

```
found = table.rows_with_country("France" )
found.each do |row|
  puts row.to_csv
end

⇒
France, Bordeaux
France, Chablis
```

What you just did is call a method named rows_with_country( ) on Ruport::Data::Table. But how could the author of this class know you were going to have a column named country? The fact is, the author didn’t know that. If you look inside Ruport, you see that both rows_with_country( ) and to_csv( ) are Ghost Methods. The Ruport::Data::Table class is somewhat as defined above.

A call to rows_with_country( ) becomes a call to a more traditional-looking
method, rows_with(:country), which takes the column name as an argu-
ment. Also, a call to to_csv( ) becomes a call to as(:csv). If the method
name doesn’t start with either of these two prefixes, Ruport falls back
to Kernel#method_missing( ), which throws a NoMethodError. (That’s what
the super keyword is for.)

Comment: Short answer: it takes the first match group and converts it to a symbol, in this case, the "rows_with_" or "to_" trailing value and either passes it on as a method parameter, or uses it as a hash key with the first arg to method_missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing(id,*args,&block)
  return as($1.to_sym,*args,&block) if id.to_s =~ /^to_(.*)/
  return rows_with($1.to_sym => args[0]) if id.to_s =~ /^rows_with_(.*)/
  super
end
```

The requisite background: `method_missing` is called on an object when the requested method isn't explicitly defined. `id` will be a Symbol of the method called; `args` will be an array of the arguments, and `block` will be a `Proc` if there was a block, or `nil`.

```
  return as($1.to_sym,*args,&block) if id.to_s =~ /^to_(.*)/
```

The execution really begins at the end, in the `if`: it checks the condition

```
id.to_s =~ /to_(.*)/
```

This basically does a match of the regexp on the string of the called method. `x =~ y` returns the integer offset in `x` of where `y` matched, if anywhere, otherwise nil.  e.g.:

```
> "abc" =~ /a/
 => 0
> "abc" =~ /.$/
 => 2
> "abc" =~ /\d/
 => nil
```

Remember that `0` is treated as truth in boolean conditions, and so the `if` will only be considered to be true if the name of the called function starts with `to_`. The rest of the method name is captured by `(.*)`.

Now, we don't explicitly save the capture groups, but Ruby borrows from Perl in that the first capture group's contents will get saved in `$1`, the second in `$2`, etc.:

```
> "abc" =~ /a(.)(.)/
 => 0
> $1
 => "b"
> $2
 => "c"
```

Now, back to the line in question:

```
  return as($1.to_sym,*args,&block) if id.to_s =~ /^to_(.*)/
```

So, if the called method's name is of the form `to_XYZ`, it calls the `as()` method with the first argument set to `:XYZ`, and the rest of the arguments from the call appended, and the block passed through (if any).

To continue on:

```
  return rows_with($1.to_sym => args[0]) if id.to_s =~ /^rows_with_(.*)/
```

This is basically the same: if the method name is like `rows_with_ABC`, then it calls `rows_with()` with a hash `{:ABC => args[0]}`, where `args[0]` is the first argument given to the missing method call.

Comment: what is the use of hash {:ABC => args[0]}

Comment: @shaileish: it's just a hash, with a single key–value mapping of `:ABC` mapping to `args[0]`. In other words, if you called `table.rows_with_country("France")` as per the example, it gets translated by `method_missing` to a call to `table.rows_with({:country => "France"})`.